# Why we should say North and South City instead of South and North City?

Tags: word-usage

Why we should say **North** and **South** City instead of **South** and **North** City??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any reason other than convention.

Other examples of standard ordering are:

> east and west
>
> left and right
>
> up and down
>
> ebb and flow

Comment: inside out / in(s) and out(s) / to and from

Comment: @Graham It doesn't apply the same way in my native language, so here we can either say 'south and north' or 'north and south'; 'west and east' or 'east and west' etc.

Comment: @May, you can say 'south and north' in English if you want - grammatically it's fine – it'll just sound a bit odd. There aren't really any rules to these conventions, its probably just a matter of picking them up over time.

Comment: See also this discussion on [*'forth and back'*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76999/is-forth-and-back-more-proper-than-back-and-forth).

Comment: @graham I was corrected by a friend, who is a British.